# Python Pyodbc Query fails with substitution param list on .join(['?', list])

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Hi I am trying to run a select query from python into a sql server. I need to only select specific files which are coming from a list from another function within my script. I wrote this function for that:

```
def flist_in_psumsdb(config, fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist):
constring = config['db_string']['db_string']
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(constring)
FilesToBeCrunched1000 = list(div_list_into_chunks(list(fnames_set_in_psumsdictlist), 1000))
file_list = set()
for FilesChunks1000 in FilesToBeCrunched1000:
    values_string = ', '.join(['?' for item in FilesChunks1000])
    sqlstring = f"""SELECT LOG FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table']} WHERE LOG IN ({values_string})"""
    # print((FilesChunks1000))
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlstring,cnxn)
    file_list.update(set(df.LOG))
```

However when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
 Execution failed on sql 'SELECT LOG FROM [NSGWSAINLINE].[dbo].[bd_psums_meta] WHERE LOG IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I printed the values string variable and it gave me this:

```
?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

Now this is very weird because I thought this was how you do joins for param substitution. What's even more weird is that this same structure works for another function I wrote to remove duplicates from the same table:

```
    for FilesChunks1000 in FilesToBeCrunched1000:
    values_string = ', '.join(['?' for item in FilesChunks1000])
    sqlstring = f"""DELETE FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table']} WHERE [LOG] IN ({values_string})"""
```

This query apparently works although when I print values_string in this function, it also returns the same result of

```
?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

So what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using '?' parameters but not providing their values anywhere

try this

```
values_string = ', '.join(["?" for item in FilesChunks1000])
sqlstring = f"""SELECT LOG FROM {config['db_string']['bd_psums_meta_table']} WHERE LOG IN ({values_string})"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlstring,cnxn, params=FilesChunks1000)
file_list.update(set(df.LOG))
```

Comment: But why does it work for the other query where i use the same format?

Comment: And does this protect against sql injection?

Comment: The second statement might be working because you might have executed sqlstring  like cnxn.execute(sqlstrin, FilesChunks1000), as values are also provided here. In case of df.read_sql(sqlstring), you haven't provided list of filenames anywhere

Comment: I see that now thanks! Does your method protect against these so called sql injection attacks?

Comment: To avoid sql injection you could use "pd.read_sql_query(sqlstring, cnxn, params=FilesChunks1000) "

Comment: Actually, why does using the '?' protect against sql injection? You are still manipulating a string no?

Comment: Actually the sql parser in the PyODBC module intenally handles the string, and checks the possible injections, doesn't  allow statement to execute and return error appropriate codes

Comment: I see. What about in general terms...outside of Pyodbc? How does doing such a '?' parameter subsititution protect better than normal string?

Comment: generally all database interfaces have such inbuilt parser, even SQLite3 module in standard Library.

Comment: By parser I assume you mean a way to check for injection attacks? GOt it. So there realy is no need for alarm then anymore. Just a matter of using best known practices?

Comment: The drivers do not "check" for injection. How would that even work? The result of a successful injection is a valid SQL statement. They prevent injection through use of placeholders (the `?` etc.) that are then replaced with provided values that have been quoted etc. correctly by the driver.